# Why won't Oracle SQLPlus run multiple statements? It's stopping at the first semicolon

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I'm trying to insert some data into a database. See here:

```
insert into membership(mem_num, fname, lname, street, city, prov, postal, balance)
values ('102', 'TAMI', 'DAWSON', '2632 TAKLI CIRCLE', 'FREDERICTON', 'NB', 'E4C 1X2', 11);
insert into membership(mem_num, fname, lname, street, city, prov, postal, balance)
values ('103', 'CURT', 'KNIGHT', '4025 CORNELL COURT', 'HALIFAX', 'NS', 'E2T 1T2', 6);
insert into membership(mem_num, fname, lname, street, city, prov, postal, balance)
values ('104', 'JAMAL', 'MELENDEZ', '788 EAST 145TH AVENUE', 'MONCTON', 'NB', 'E4C 1U2', 0);
insert into membership(mem_num, fname, lname, street, city, prov, postal, balance)
values ('105', 'IVA', 'MCCLAIN', '6045 MUSKET BALL CIRCLE', 'SUMMIT', 'NB', 'E4T 1J2', 15);
insert into membership(mem_num, fname, lname, street, city, prov, postal, balance)
values ('106', 'MIRANDA', 'PARKS', '4469 MAXWELL PLACE', 'GERMANTOWN', 'NB', 'E2H 1S2', 0);
insert into membership(mem_num, fname, lname, street, city, prov, postal, balance)
values ('107', 'ROSARIO', 'ELLIOTT', '7578 DANNER AVENUE', 'TRACEY', 'NB', 'E4C 1G2', 5);
insert into membership(mem_num, fname, lname, street, city, prov, postal, balance)
values ('108', 'MATTIE', 'GUY', '4390 EVERGREEN STREET', 'LILY', 'NS', 'E2K 1F2', 0);
```

So I've got this in my scripts folder. I load it into the buffer with "Get myScript.sql", then run it, and I get this error:

```
values ('102', 'TAMI', 'DAWSON', '2632 TAKLI CIRCLE', 'FREDERICTON', 'NB', 'E4C 1X2', 11);
                                                                                         *
ERROR at line 2: 
ORA-00911: invalid character
```

It seems to be referring to the semicolon as the invalid character. If I run the statements one at a time, i.e just:

```
insert into membership(mem_num, fname, lname, street, city, prov, postal, balance)
values ('102', 'TAMI', 'DAWSON', '2632 TAKLI CIRCLE', 'FREDERICTON', 'NB', 'E4C 1X2', 11);
```

And then move onto the next one, each works perfectly. I just can't run them all at once. Running them all at once works fine on someone else's machine. From what I can tell, SQLPlus is for some reason trying always to execute it as one statement, thus the error when it hits a semicolon part way through. Does anyone know how to change this to get it working right?

Comment: Does it work properly if you run the file using `@myscript`?

Comment: Actually, yes! That's very helpful, thank you. Still, it definitely should work from the buffer

Comment: You can also wrap them with a begin and end; commands to turn it into a plssql block.  It's a compiling issue sqlplus has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong. SQLPlus won't take multiple statements in the buffer directly. You can copy/paste them in all at once, and it will execute them one by one, or you can run the script file with @myFile.sql, but you cannot load multiple statements and execute them directly in the buffer: i.e

```
get myFile.sql
/
```

Answer (score 0):

A semicolon in SQL*Plus means "I've finished typing". Get rid of the semicolon and put a / between statement lines to execute what is in the buffer.

```
insert blah
/
insert blah
/
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean with `I load it into the buffer with "Get myScript.sql", then run it` or why you would want to load something into a buffer in SQLPlus, but I run scripts with many insert statements all the time without any problems.

It appears that you have a script file already, so just call it in your SQLPlus shell:

```
@Get myScript.sql
```

No buffer needed.